# How to call a class=“selected” to main menu level while select any sub level of a dropdown menu

Tags: php, drop-down-menu

I need to call `class="selected"` to main menu level while select any sub level . How to stay selected on "SERVICES" & "EDUCATION" level while select "SCHOOL" or "COLLEGE".

```
<ul>
 <li><a href="#">SERVICES</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">EDUCATION</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="school.php"<?=echoSelectedClassIfRequestMatches("school")?>>SCHOOL</a></li>
                        <li><a href="college.php"<?=echoSelectedClassIfRequestMatches("college")?>>COLLEGE</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>           
                <li><a href="courier.php"<?=echoSelectedClassIfRequestMatches("courier")?>>COURIER</a></li>
                <li><a href="bank.php"<?=echoSelectedClassIfRequestMatches("bank")?>>BANK</a></li>
                <li><a href="hotel.php"<?=echoSelectedClassIfRequestMatches("hotel")?>>HOTEL</a></li>
            </ul>
  </li>
 </ul>
```

PHP

```
<?php
function echoSelectedClassIfRequestMatches($requestUri)
{
$current_file_name = basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], ".php");

if ($current_file_name == $requestUri)
    echo 'class="selected"';
}
?>
```

Comment: if the purpose is styling then just use css selector of parent of active child

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Using CSS

My advice, stick some CSS classes on your menu tags, have PHP simply spit out a class indicating the current page, and do the rest in CSS.

For example:

```
<ul class="nav page-<?php echo basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], ".php") ?>">
 <li><a href="#">SERVICES</a>
            <ul>
                <li class="education"><a href="#">EDUCATION</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="school.php">SCHOOL</a></li>
                        <li><a href="college.php">COLLEGE</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>           
                <li class="courier"><a href="courier.php">COURIER</a></li>
                <li class="bank"><a href="bank.php">BANK</a></li>
                <li class="hotel"><a href="hotel.php">HOTEL</a></li>
            </ul>
  </li>
 </ul>
```

The only PHP code is the one line spitting out your current page name as a CSS class.

Now you can do something like this:

```
<style>
.nav.page-education .education,
.nav.page-school .education,
.nav.page-college .education,
.nav.page-courier .courier,
.nav.page-bank .bank,
.nav.page-hotel .hotel {
    /** This is your 'selected' styling **/
    color: red;
}
</style>
```

Easy! Avoids mixing a lot of PHP with your HTML code.

### Using PHP

If you really want to stick with your current approach, I'd make the following changes:

```
function echoSelectedClassIfRequestMatches($requestUri)
{
    if(requestMatches($requestUri)) {
        echo 'class="selected"';
    }
}

/**
 * Determine if the current file name matches a particular request.
 * Accepts a string or array for $requestUri
 */ 
function requestMatches($requestUri) {
    $current_file_name = basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], ".php");

    return (is_array($requestUri))
        ? in_array($current_file_name, $requestUri)
        : $current_file_name == $requestUri;
}
```

Now your function optionally accepts an array of page names. So you can do this:

```
<li><a href="#" <?=echoSelectedClassIfRequestMatches(["school","college]) ?>>EDUCATION</a>
```

By passing in an array here, you can echo `class="selected"` for multiple page names.

Comment: I need this php function exactly ...  Thank you for your help.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Did the PHP solution I provided work for you?

Comment: it works fine but while mouse hover on selected menu , top level selection disappear immediately. sub level selection is Ok.

Comment: That means you need to review your `:hover` style carefully, since you only have a problem on hover. I obviously can't see the issue from here.

Comment: That PHP function worked for me . Thank you once again.